# DataDirectory C#

Tags: c#, sql, conexão

Eu preciso de uma string de conexão flexível para que ela automaticamente procure na pasta do programa pelo **arquivo .mdf**.

Meu seguinte código está assim:

```
public Form1()
    {
        string relative = @"..\..\Database1.mdf";
        string absolute = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(relative);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", absolute);
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show(absolute);
        SqlConnection conex = new SqlConnection(absolute);
    }
```

A variável *absolute* ao ser exibida no `MessageBox` funciona perfeitamente, dá o local exato do meu arquivo *.mdf*.
Porém ao colocar no parâmetro `sqlConnection`, gera um **erro**:

> O formato da cadeia de inicialização não está de acordo com a especificação iniciada no índice 0.

No arquivo app.config da pasta do programa eu editei também pra algo assim:

```
connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Initial Catalog=Cos;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Então, o único problema é que eu **não consigo** usar a variável **absolute** como parâmetro no método `SqlConnection`.

Comment: relacionado a tema continuação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156488/como-preparar-o-programa-para-uso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O construtor da classe SqlConnection recebe como parâmetro a ConnectionString inteira. Não apenas a localização do banco.

Você já tentou concatenar o caminho do arquivo na connection string e passar para o construtor?

Por exemplo, talvez algo assim:

```
public Form1()
{
    string relative = @"..\..\Database1.mdf";
    string absolute = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(relative);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", absolute);
    InitializeComponent();
    MessageBox.Show(absolute);

    // Buscar a connection string já concatenada com o caminho:
    var connectionString = GetConnectionString(absolute);
    MessageBox.Show(connectionString);

    SqlConnection conex = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}

public string GetConnectionString(string absolutePath)
{
    return string.Format("Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={0};Initial Catalog=Cos;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True", absolutePath);
}
```